# How can I rename a large set of photos using their modified date?

Tags: metadata, file-management

My problem is a little bit different from the other that I've seen here. The thing is that I have for example: DSCF0001, DSCF0002 and so on, as filenames with modified dates 2020/01/01 , 2020/01/02 (just to simplify the example, consider that there is only one photo per day).
The problem is: sometimes, it happens that DSCF0020 has a 2020/01/21 and DSCF0021 has a 2020/01/20 date. In this case, I would like an app that:

1. warning that the sequence in the names are not the same as the sequence in dates.
2. give me some flexibility to rename the files and give me some options of what to do with the others.
   I've tried to rename my files with bulk rename utility, but I couldn't make the program to check it for me.
   And last question, why does it happen? It's a bit strange for me this behaviour. My guess is that the date is wrong, since in these cases the order given by the names makes much more sense.

Thank you

Comment: Which operating system do you use?

Comment: Also this might be better suited for https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com as this is almost unrelated to photography as filenames and modification dates are file system properties.

Comment: Date modified will change every time a file is… modified. Much more reliable would be date created - though that will still fail if you save out as PSD from RAW, etc. Personally I file by having the folder dated, followed by the event that folder relates to. keeps everything organised with no need to mess with individual names.

Comment: Tetsujin, the way you describe the date modified and date created is the same that I used to think about it. However, in my folders there is a lot of photos that has date creation after date modified. I think that it has some relation with the fact that I copied them to another drive. So that's the reason I am using date modified.

Comment: Matt, I am using windows. Next time I will use the softwaerecs. Thank u.

Comment: @RodrigoMiyamoto You need to use a tool that understands Exif.  Then the timestamp would be when the photo was taken.

Comment: The OS/File System date/time of creation/modification is not usually very reliable and is especially poor on Windows. You need to use the date & time that the photo was created - EXIF Tool (Free from https://exiftool.org/) is great for extracting that information.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about file handling/naming, not photography, and is better suited to a software or programming stack.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that "*filenames with modified dates 2020/01/01*" refers to the filesystem timestamps, and not the EXIF data.

As others have and will point out, this is difficult to maintain (e.g. every time you edit the EXIF data, the file's change date will become wrong).

But if all you want is something to provide a quick check as to whether the files are consistently dated, say just before you use the timestamps to set the EXIF dates, this will do the trick.

---

If you have access to a `bash` shell and the `ls` command (e.g. as on Linux systems):

```
$ ls -ltr
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ray ray 0 Jan 19  2020 DSCF0019
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ray ray 0 Jan 20  2020 DSCF0021
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ray ray 0 Jan 21  2020 DSCF0020
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ray ray 0 Jan 22  2020 DSCF0022

$ ls
DSCF0019  DSCF0020  DSCF0021  DSCF0022

$ ls -tr
DSCF0019  DSCF0021  DSCF0020  DSCF0022

$ diff <(ls -tr) <(ls)
2d1
< DSCF0021
3a3
> DSCF0021
```

The `ls` command lists the files sorted by name.

The `ls -tr` command lists the files sorted by change date (-r means oldest first).

The `diff` command compares the two results and displays what is different.

Answer (score 0):

I used **XnView** for batch renaming.
XnView is a **free** Image Viewer to easily open and edit your photo file.
You can try to use photo`s Modified date or EXIF data (if it exists) in renaming rules.

Here my settings for renaming:

[image]

Comment: But it is possible to do the check that I want in XnView?

Comment: Of course, you can see new names BEFORE you will rename photos.

Comment: Actually, the problem is that I have to see all the original names one by one to check if the order given by them is the same as the order given by date modified or EXIF. The solution that I've found is to work with some package like exifr in R that can give me the flexibility that I wanted.